# How to obtain the redirect url after html submit button clicked in web browser control in c#?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-console

I have created a console application that logs into a website then clicks a submit button on another page (page2) in the site. The login and the page2 pages are accessed using different threads. Now I want to access the url that the browser should be redirected to after clicking the submit button. How do I access that? Below is the code for the Document_Completed event.

```
 private static void Br_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
          WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
          //Retrieve string content of document
          var document = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;
           if (wb.Url.ToString().Contains("login"))
           {
            wb.Document.GetElementById("name").SetAttribute("value", 
            "ABC");
            wb.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", 
            "pwd");
            wb.Document.GetElementById("password2fa").SetAttribute("value", 
            "1999");
            foreach (HtmlElement el in wb.Document.All)
                if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "pure-button pure- 
                    button-primary sign-in-button")
                    el.InvokeMember("click");
            }
            else if(wb.Url.ToString().Contains("authorize"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement el in wb.Document.All)
                    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "pure-button pure- 
                        button-primary allow-btn")
                     el.InvokeMember("click");

            }

            s = wb.Url.AbsoluteUri;

            if (wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Contains("TOKEN"))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new 
                System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\IISHost\WriteLines2.txt"))
                {

                    file.WriteLine(wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
                }

             }
             Application.ExitThread();


         }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Navigating` event?

Comment: Yes..that seems to be it.

Comment: This does not work..It is giving me the same url as page2, how do I get the url when the button redirects it to the next page.